# Running AndroidTest on Library project not working anymore

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-gradle-plugin

I do have a project with an app and a library module that contains JNI code. I added a test class to the 'androidTest' folder in order to test all this in a device environment.

At the time doing, Android Studio 2.2.2 was able to identify the code as test (adding all the nice icons to run the whole class test and so on).

Now (a large number of commits and git rebasing later) I want to do some more work, but Android Studio refuses to accept the code as test code, although gradle itself (invoked with `:libname:connectedAndroidTest`) does perform the tests and writes timing info into some XML in the `./build/outputs/androidTest-results/connected` of the library module folder.

The AS editor marks all unit testing related imports in red. When I try to resolve the "problem" AS suggests to "Add library 'runner-0.5' to classpath" although `build.gradle` already contains that reference.
AFAIR I was also able to select the library module in the "Module" setting in the General tab of the Android Test run configuration. But that doesn't work anymore.

What puzzles me is, that I some had this all working from within the IDE and now it doesn't work anymore. Although the gradle call will still run the test cases that the compiler doesn't complain about anything...

Any ideas anybody?

PS:
I do know that I can move the "androidTest" code into a differen module. However I do already have 10+ modules in my project. And since gradle is able to run the test, why is Android Studio not anymore?